# Mocha testing throws AssertionError

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, assert

I'm working on a simple testing scripts with mocha and coffeescript.

In my test folder, I have a configuration for mocha( *mocha.opts* ):

```
--compilers coffee: coffee-script/register
--reporter spec
```

And my testing file ( *test_one.coffee* ):

```
assert = require "assert"

describe "A feature", ->
    describe "An specific function", ->
        it "Should work as expected", ->
            assert true
```

But whenever I run "mocha ." it returns me this:

```
assert.js:93

 throw new assert.AssertionError({ 

 AssertionError: missing path
     at Module.require (module.js:363:3)
     at require (module.js:380:17)
     at args (C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bi
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
     at startup (node.js:119:16)
     at node.js:929:3
```

Any ideas of how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to pass to Mocha is: `--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register`. Note the lack of space after the colon.

I believe what is happening is that with the space, it tells Mocha that to compile `coffee` files, it should load a module with a path which is an empty string, and you get the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

*As a reference for anyone looking for this error.*

This is almost always an error in the string passed in `package.json`
mine was:

```
"test": "mocha --reporter spec --compilers ts:ts-node/register, 'test/**/*.test.ts'"
```

Notice the comma after the word **register**